# Is const A aref = 3 equivalent to int & const aref = 3 OR int & aref = 3

Tags: c++, reference, constants, typedef

I am learning C++ using the resources listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). I came across the following [claim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26083187/12002570) which **I think is incorrect**:

> ```
> typedef int& A;
> const A aref = 3;
> ```
>
> because it is equivalent to
>
> ```
> int & const aref = 3;
> ```

---

As you can see in the above code snippet the user claims that `const A aref` is equivalent to `int & const aref`. Now, **my question is** that is the above claim technically correct?

I don't think so. Because the standard specifically says that:

> **Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef-name** (7.1.3, 14.1) or decltype-specificer (7.1.6.2), in which case the cv-qualifiers are **ignored**

This means that `const A aref = 3;` is actually equivalent to:

```
//---v------------>no const here because it is ignored
int & aref = 3;   //the actual problem is that a non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to rvalue
```

That is, the actual problem is that "a non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to an rvalue" and **not that** "we have are applying `const` to a reference".

So is my analysis correct and the claim by the user is incorrect?

Comment: It is equivalent to `int & aref = 3` and your analysis is correct.

Comment: You can confirm your analysis with `static_assert(std::is_same_v<const A, int &>);`.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is correct and the claim is incorrect because `const A aref = 3;` is equivalent to:

```
int & aref = 3;
```

which will not work(as you already pointed out in your question) because a non const lvalue reference cannot bind to rvalue.

You **can  even confirm this** using `static_assert` as shown below:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<const A, int &>); //passes
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Ukga0OqNg)

This confirms that it is equivalent to `int & aref = 3;`.

Or even just trying out the code in gcc and you'll get the error saying:

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘A {aka int&}’ to an rvalue of type ‘int’
```